# How to make this code cleaner? react native

Tags: react-native, coding-style, react-navigation

I am building a stack navigator and want to make it cleaner I Tried many times but I couldn't

here is my code,

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const {isSignedIn} = useSelector(state => state.authReducer);

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      {isSignedIn ? (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={HomeDrawer} />
          <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ProductOverview" component={ProductOverview} />
          <Stack.Screen name="CartScreen" component={CartScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="OrderOverview" component={OrderOverview} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
          <Stack.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={HomeDrawer} />
          <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ProductOverview" component={ProductOverview} />
          <Stack.Screen name="CartScreen" component={CartScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="OrderOverview" component={OrderOverview} />
        </>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I don't want to duplicate code like this, Is there is a way to not duplicate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function Navigation() {
const {isSignedIn} = useSelector(state => state.authReducer);

return (
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
    {!isSignedIn && (
      <>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
      </>
    )}
    <Stack.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={HomeDrawer} />
    <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ProductOverview" component={ProductOverview} />
    <Stack.Screen name="CartScreen" component={CartScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="OrderOverview" component={OrderOverview} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

}

Hey, try this. I haven't tried executing this, since I don't have the environment setup now. But it should work. Hope it helps. Cheers.